# When displaying array, I am having repeated values that are not in the array

Tags: php, arrays, count

Ok, I am beating my head on my PC…. I do not know what is going on. I’m using PHP to make a soap call to a remote database… I am running 4 queries, merging two multidimensional arrays and returning them.

The array looks clean, but when I display the results, they are repeating.

Here is one example after call:

```
$row = $response;
$count = count($row);
for($i=0;$i<=$count-1;$i++){
$product = $row[$i]['Product'];
$color = $row[$i]['Color'];
$type = $row[$i]['Type'];
$length = $row[$i]['Length'];
$render = '<li><div id="somediv">strong>' . $product . '</strong><br />Color: ' . $color . '<br />' .  ‘ Size: ' . $length .  '<input type="button" value="value" onclick="someaction(' . $i . ')" />' . '</div></li>';
}
```

Here is a repeated problem from the array returned  :

```
[11] => Array ( 
                    [Product] => Some Product 
                    [Color] => Some Color 
                    [Type] => C 
                    [Length] => 150 
              )
```

However the it repeats the same occurrence.. it only does this with a handful of products:

**Some Product**
          Color: some color
          Size: 150
          Price: 4.79

```
</li>
```

**Some Product**
          Color: some color
          Size: 150
          Price: 4.79

```
</li>
```

**Some Product**
          Color: some color
          Size: 150
          Price: 4.79

```
</li>
```

**Some Product**
          Color: some color
          Size: 150
          Price: 4.79

```
</li>
```

Comment: Then maybe it comes from your response? Do a print_r of your response.

Comment: "$render =" should be "$render .=", no?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I was going to update my answer. I had put to if statements at the end of the foreach, and it would repeat an element for the elements that were not there. I had two original if statements, so I moved the final if statements to the the if statements they basically represented and it worked.

here was first code example:

```
<?php 
$row = $response;

$count = count($row);




for($i=0;$i<=$count-1;$i++){

@$type = $row[$i]['Type'];  

if ($type == 'something') {
$someproduct = $row[$i]['someproduct'];
$somecolor = $row[$i]['somecolor'];
$length = $row[$i]['Length'];




if ($type == 'this') {



$img = 'myimage';

$this = $img . '<div id="somediv"><br /><strong>' . $someproduct . 'somecolor: ' . $somecolor . '<input type="button" value="value" onclick="somefunction(' . $i . ')" />' . '</div></div></li>';




}
if ($type == 'that') {



$img = 'myimage';

$that = $img . '<div id="somediv"><br /><strong>' . $someproduct . 'somecolor: ' . $somecolor . '<input type="button" value="value" onclick="somefunction(' . $i . ')" />' . '</div></div></li>';




}




if (!isset($whatever) || $whatever == 'that') {


echo $that;


}

if (!isset($whatever) || $whatever == 'this') {


echo $this;


}




}
}



?>
```

Here is the change.. I've been working on this project so long, I'm overlooking small stuff that I should know.

```
<?php 
$row = $response;

$count = count($row);




for($i=0;$i<=$count-1;$i++){

@$type = $row[$i]['Type'];  

if ($type == 'something') {
$someproduct = $row[$i]['someproduct'];
$somecolor = $row[$i]['somecolor'];
$length = $row[$i]['Length'];




if ($type == 'this') {



$img = 'myimage';

$this = $img . '<div id="somediv"><br /><strong>' . $someproduct . 'somecolor: ' . $somecolor . '<input type="button" value="value" onclick="somefunction(' . $i . ')" />' . '</div></div></li>';


if (!isset($whatever) || $whatever == 'this') {


echo $this;


}

}
if ($type == 'that') {



$img = 'myimage';

$that = $img . '<div id="somediv"><br /><strong>' . $someproduct . 'somecolor: ' . $somecolor . '<input type="button" value="value" onclick="somefunction(' . $i . ')" />' . '</div></div></li>';


if (!isset($whatever) || $whatever == 'that') {


echo $that;


}

}









}
}



?>
```

Thanks for the advice and help

Answer (score 0):

Do a `print_r($row)` which will show you what is in your array. If the values are there, it's not an issue with the printing, it's with generating the array.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I'm a dummy... I forgot I was hidden some values, so it was repeating until the next unhide value was shown